# Amazon ec2 not instantiate with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am working on amazon ec2. When i integrated the code giving following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Aws\Exception\CredentialsException' with message 'Error retrieving credentials from the instance profile metadata server. (cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 1996 milliseconds

Here is my code

```
require __DIR__ . '/aws.phar';

$client = Aws\S3\S3Client::factory([
'key'    => '[********]',
'secret' => '[************]',
'region' => '[us-east-1]', // (e.g., us-east-1)
'version' => 'latest'
]);

echo $client->listBuckets();
```

Comment: I hope that's not your real key and secret.

Comment: Did my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 0):

`Key` and `Secret` shouldn't include `[` and `]`. Can you try:

```
'key'    => '********',
'secret' => '************',
'region' => 'us-east-1',
```

[Passing credentials into a client factory method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/guide/credentials.html#factory-credentials)

```
// Instantiate the S3 client with your AWS credentials
$s3Client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => 'YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
        'secret' => 'YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
    )
));
```